# Can I not only run but also manage another compliled .exe with a program I make in c#?

Tags: c#

I know you can run .exe with a click of a button, its quite simple to do.

What I want to try to do is run a .exe in the background (hidden) and manage it from the tool I am working on in C#.

I am working with proxies & I found a great proxy scraper I would like to implement into my tool without having the proxy scraper show or pop up, I would like my tool to basically just be the interface of the scraper. 
(the scraper is a small add on to my tool, I am not trying to rip the scraper)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Control console application from Windows form application C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760341/control-console-application-from-windows-form-application-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't see how in that post they would know where to put the text from one form to the other form. I only see read.

Comment: The problem is going to be that Windows typically expects UI events on visible controls. If you try to hide the UI of the other application, GDI isn't going to work properly because the Windows API isn't going to recognize the events fired on the other app's controls.

Comment: what if I were to open and minimize the application behind the UI ?

Comment: Is your "great proxy scraper" a console program? If so, the proposed duplicate (along with the hundreds of other questions on Stack Overflow asking about this scenario) answers your question. If not, then your question is at best too broad. You can use `SendKeys` or UI automation to control other GUI processes, but how specifically to do this depends on the other process. You need to provide a good [mcve] illustrating your scenario and explain what _specifically_ you need help with.